# Graphics doesn't change after redrawing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, graphics, pacman

I am making a simple Pacman game using c# in Visual studio (using Windows Forms).

[image: Pacman]

Hovewer, I can't figure out why the image doesn't change when the pacman eats the pill.

My code fragments:

**PacmanGame.cs**

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        Graphics dc = e.Graphics;
        _maze.DrawMaze(dc);
        // + some other code
        base.OnPaint(e);
        }
private void timeGameLoop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    _character.Move(); //pacman's movement
    Invalidate();
     // + some other code
    }
```

**Maze.cs**

```
public List<string> lines { get; set; }
private bool[,] eaten; // true if pill was eaten

public void DrawMaze(Graphics gfx)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
                {
                    // 2 indicates pill (white)
                    if (lines[i][x] == '2' && eaten[i, x] == false)
                    {
                        gfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(x * 2 - 6, i * 2 - 6, 12, 12));
                    }

                    // 3 indicates power pill (red)
                    else if (lines[i][x] == '3' && eaten[i, x] == false)
                    {
                        gfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(x * 2 - 6, i * 2 - 6, 15, 15));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
public void Eat(int row, int column)
        {
            eaten[row, column] = true;
        }
```

**Pacman.cs**

```
public void Move()
{
      // Left - x of pacman's position, Top - y of pacman's position
      if (_maze.lines[Left][Top] == '2' || _maze.lines[Left][Top] == '3')
      {
            _maze.Eat(Left, Top);
      }

      //other code to continue moving...
 }
```

The map doesn't update (eaten pills don't disappear) after pacman eats them. How can I solve it?

Comment: Really you should be keeping a `List` of `Pill` class and remove the as they get eaten. Each `Pill` knows how to draw itself and your main draw method will just loop the list and pass the `Graphics` for drawing

Comment: I see no line where you Invalidate (or Refresh) the maze; without it Paint won't be called...

Comment: Sory, forgot to copy one line

I edited my question (PacmanGame.cs class) Anyway the problem still exists

Comment: What does the debugger say? Do you enter the Eat code? Also: Your code seems to mix row/column vs left/top. row should be y or top, column = x = left !! Change `eaten[row, column] = true;` to `eaten[column, row] = true;` etc..

Comment: @TaW debugger says that I've entered Eat code. I've also swapped row and column, but it doesnt changed anything. More surprisingly,after this change sometimes I get IndexOutOfRangeException in this: eaten[column, row] = true; even when the Pacman is moving in the middle of the maze.

Comment: Did you change __all__ the wrong references or just the one I quoted?

Comment: @TaW yes, I did:
public int Movement(string requestedDirection)
        {
            if (_maze.lines[Top][Left] == '2' || _maze.lines[Top][Left] == '3')
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("eating..." + Left + " " + Top);
                score++;
                _maze.Eat(Top, Left);
            }
}

and:

public void Eat(int row, int column)
        {
            eaten[column, row] = true;
            Console.WriteLine(eaten[column, row]);
        }